# What's the opposite of the Window.Activate function?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a loop timer. When the time is up, I bring the MainWindow to the front with the Activate() function.
When the user dismisses the alarm with a button, I want to send the window back behind the other open windows until the alarm goes off again.

I have tried
`SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 100, 100, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);`
but this seems to permanently put my window in the background, and the next call of Activate() does not bring it forward again.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with just closing the window and the re-creating it next time you need it?

Comment: Instead of calling `Activate`, can't you activate it using the `SetWindowPos` method? Try to replace `HWND_BOTTOM` with `HWND_TOP`.

Comment: mm8 thanks for the suggestion! If I call `SetWindowPos` with `HWND_TOP` and `HWND_BOTTOM`, the window pops up just fine, but does not go back to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new window just to dismiss the alarm, calling Activate() on it, to get it to the top, and then closing it when the button is pressed.

Not what I wanted, but it works.

Peregrine thanks for the idea!